# Minimal size of $a^2+b^2$ such that $ad-bc=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

If $c,d$ are two relatively prime positive integers, then we can find integers $a,b$ such that $ad-bc=1$. But $a$ and $b$ are not unique: we can replace $a$ with $a+kc$ and $b$ with $b+kd$ for any integer $k$ and get another solution. So there is a solution $(a,b)$ of minimal distance from the origin, in the sense that $a^2+b^2$ is smallest possible, and in fact that's the solution found via the Euclidean algorithm. My question is: what can we say about the size of $a^2+b^2$ for the minimal solution? Is it true that $a^2+b^2$ is always less than $c^2+d^2$?

Comment: If it helps: just by considering the quadratic function $(a + k c)^2 + (b + k d)^2$ of $k$, the real number $k$ that minimizes it is $k=-(ac+bd)/(c^2+d^2)$ and at that $k$-value the function takes the value $1/(c^2+d^2)$. The minimal integer solution will arise from either $\lfloor -(ac+bd)/(c^2+d^2) \rfloor$ or $\lceil -(ac+bd)/(c^2+d^2) \rceil$.

Comment: The answer is contained in solving [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670405/does-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-always-return-the-smallest-coefficients-of) about whether the extended Euclidean algorithm does find the smallest coefficients.  In terms of the present notation it is shown (by induction on the number of steps needed) that if $c \gt d$, then $|a| \le c/2$ and $|b| \le d/2$.  Thus $a^2 + b^2 \le c^2$.  If you agree, we can mark this Question as a duplicate.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) presents only a weaker claim, so it might be worth having an Answer here to sort out the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: See my comment on this question:' Given $a$ in $\gcd(a,b)$ with $a > b > 0$, how can I find $b$ which give the maximum number of steps($l$) for the Euclidean algorithm?'

I found the size of $a^2+b^2$ depends on the number of steps for the Euclidian algorithm. Look at this example from my previous comment:

$1437\times4277-2048\times 3001=1$

1)) Number of steps: 10

2)) $a^2+b^2=6259273$

3)) $c^2+d^2=27298730$

$\Rightarrow a^2+b^2<c^2+d^2$

For the same $d=4277$ we also have:

$1788\times 4277-2825\times 2707=1$

1)) Number of steps: 10

2)) $a^2+b^2=11156149$

3)) $c^2+d^2=25620578$

4)) $\Rightarrow a^2+b^2<c^2+d^2$

Comparing these two we Find:

$(l=10):a^2+b^2=11156149>6259273; (l=6)$

we predict revers for $c^2+d^2$ and it is true and shown below:

$(l=6): c^2+d^2=27298730> 25620578; (l=10)$

So in both cases  $a^2+b^2<c^2+d^2$.

Comment: I don't think this solves the Question.  At best it checks a few examples, and drawing a connection with another Question is not well explained.

Comment: @hardmath, I like to see an alternative or counter example.I used the examples from my previous comment, this is the connection.

Comment: It looks like you are referring to this [previous Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675325/3111) from about one year ago.  I've given a link to an older Question above where the claim is proved in a fairly strong form.

Comment: @hardmath, Correct. How can I refer to a question by a code in Latex?Where is your link?